# Multiple ethernet network profiles in windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, profile, lan

I have a college lan connection with static ip address and a Home internet connection(wired) with dynamic DHCP working. I need to frequently change the tcp/ip v4 settings in the properties of local area connection.

Is there a way I can have 2 network profiles for wired connections- one for college and one for home so that i can simply select which one to use.

Actually I want to be able to use this functionality to ultimately write a batch file that automatically detects my proxy settings and sets the system proxy settings, so that the browser settings also don't have to be changed everytime I switch the profiles. I was able to do it in ubuntu using a bash script. I want to do the same in windows.

Comment: Why not just move the questions to Superuser rather than closing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Alternate IP Address Configuration](http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.com/2011/03/windows-7-alternate-ip-address.html) that is available in Windows

Comment: yes i did, but that did not seem to be working. I am in college right now and i was actually giving it a try. The alternate ip address configuration thing gets enabled only when the first configuration is set to automatic and so i set the static settings in the alternate configuration but i could not connect to the internet.

Comment: It takes some time to kick in. But it works! Its a simple solution for 2 lan configurations I think. Thanks @Mark Hall.